# Regex for lookaround to fetch the matched contents

Tags: perl

My Code:

```
#--------------->
sub FigureMoves
#--------------->
{
    my $FigMove = shift;

    my ($fpre,$fmatchs,$fposts) = "";
    while($FigMove=~m/(\S)\s?\\begin\{(figure\d+)\}((?:(?!\\end\{\2\}).)*)\\end\{\2\}\s?(\S)/gs)
    {
        $fpre = $fpre.$`; $fmatchs = $&; $fposts = $';

        print "$fmatchs\n";

        $fpre = $fpre.$fmatchs; $FigMove = $fposts;
    }
    if(length $fpre) {  $FigMove = $fpre.$fposts;  }

    return $FigMove;
}
```

Input Contents:

```
r_{2}, T)$ for any $ T>0  $. This fact is verified by the numerical
simulation in Figure 1.

\begin{figure1}
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=14cm]{liu1727.eps}\\
  \caption{Numerical solutions $x(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))^T$ of systems (3.1) for  initial value $(1.2,-1.3)^T, (0.3,-0.4)^T$. }
\end{figure1}

From (3.2), we can choose $\sigma=0.01$ such that $(2.15)$ holds.

stability for FCNNs with   proportional delays and oscillating
leakage coefficients.  In particular, such topic has not been
\begin{figure3}
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}2
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=14cm]{liu2727.eps}\\
  \caption{Synchronous errors of system (3.1) $x(t)-x^*(t)=(x_1(t)-x_1^*(t),x_2(t)-x_2^*(t))^T$  with  initial value $(2,-3)^T, (-7,6)^T, (4,-5)^T$. }
\end{figure3}
touched in most recently references [28--33] on FCNNs.
 Thus, all the results in these literature and the references
```

In this case I found single and double entermark before *begin{figure}* and *end{figure}*. If the single entermark found before and after the *figure* then I delete the *figure* and merge the line with the previous line.

> For example figure3 should be deleted and the line should be merged with previous line.
>
> "*stability for FCNNs with   proportional delays and oscillating
> leakage coefficients.  In particular, such topic has not **been touched** in most recently references [28--33] on FCNNs.
> Thus, all the results in these literature and the references*"

Could you please anyone give a path to get the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to well understand your needs, but a simple replace should work:

```
my $FigMove = <<'EOD';
r_{2}, T)$ for any $ T>0  $. This fact is verified by the numerical
simulation in Figure 1.

\begin{figure1}
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=14cm]{liu1727.eps}\\
  \caption{Numerical solutions $x(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))^T$ of systems (3.1) for  initial value $(1.2,-1.3)^T, (0.3,-0.4)^T$. }
\end{figure1}

From (3.2), we can choose $\sigma=0.01$ such that $(2.15)$ holds.

stability for FCNNs with   proportional delays and oscillating
leakage coefficients.  In particular, such topic has not been
\begin{figure3}
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}2
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=14cm]{liu2727.eps}\\
  \caption{Synchronous errors of system (3.1) $x(t)-x^*(t)=(x_1(t)-x_1^*(t),x_2(t)-x_2^*(t))^T$  with  initial value $(2,-3)^T, (-7,6)^T, (4,-5)^T$. }
\end{figure3}
touched in most recently references [28--33] on FCNNs.
 Thus, all the results in these literature and the references
EOD


$FigMove =~ s/(?<!\n)\n\\begin\{(figure\d+)\}((?:(?!\\end\{\1\}).)*)\\end\{\1\}\n(?!\n)//gs;
print $FigMove,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
r_{2}, T)$ for any $ T>0  $. This fact is verified by the numerical
simulation in Figure 1.

\begin{figure1}
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=14cm]{liu1727.eps}\\
  \caption{Numerical solutions $x(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))^T$ of systems (3.1) for  initial value $(1.2,-1.3)^T, (0.3,-0.4)^T$. }
\end{figure1}

From (3.2), we can choose $\sigma=0.01$ such that $(2.15)$ holds.

stability for FCNNs with   proportional delays and oscillating
leakage coefficients.  In particular, such topic has not beentouched in most recently references [28--33] on FCNNs.
 Thus, all the results in these literature and the references
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. _For example figure3 should be deleted and the line should be merged with previous line_

Comment: The scenario is merge lines around with figure opening and closing while around having a single enter. Not consider the double enter before and after in figures.

Comment: Yes. This is what I expected. Awesome.